# Scala ,sbt and emma or Cobertura

Tags: scala, sbt, cobertura, emma

I want to use code coverage in Scala project,Simple Build Tool used as a build tool.What is the best one to use in this project. (I'm new to these technologies.) Any one can tell me how to configure code coverage in my project.If you could provide an example that will help me lot to understand the things.

Comment: What about Jacoco, for me it works! http://ronalleva.com/2012/04/25/jacoco-and-play.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to figure out the same thing right now :-)

I've found the [sbt-undercover-plugin](https://github.com/NumberFour/sbt-undercover-plugin), which uses [Undercover](http://code.google.com/p/undercover/) to generate a pretty nice looking HTML report for code coverage.  I worked really well the first time I used it, but this morning my reports all show 0% coverage, so YMMV.

I'll update as I find other options.

*Edit:*

The [Scala Code Coverage Tool](http://mtkopone.github.com/scct/) looks a bit more robust.  It at least provides its own Maven repo, so you don't have to deploy locally to your build machines.

Comment: thanxx,If you found any updates regrading this please let me know

Comment: I'm having good luck with Scala Code Coverage Tool.  It seems to have fewer snags that sbt-undercover-plugin.

Comment: scct plugin does not work for me. It report enormously high coverage. It does not show untested code but it generates perfect reports fr a manager.

Comment: did anyone figure out yet how to use sbt-scct plugin on SBT multiproject setup? For some reason my Build.scala can't find ScctPlugin object. It seems that it should be in default package and import ScctPlugin does not work. I followed instructions on their home page. Any help would be appreciated.